# spring limit max sessions ; limit max users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

may i know possible to use spring security to limit max number of users able to login to website at the same time?

definately, not concurrent-session-control  parameter.  what i want is for instance, i want to limit maximum only allow 1000 users login same time. if more than that forward to notice page stating maximum users exceeded

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Spring Security's concurrent session control by accessing the SessionRegistry to find out how many users are currently logged in. In Spring Security 3, the ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy is responsible for controlling whether the user is allowed to create a session after logging in. You can extend this class and add an extra check based on the number of users:

```
public class MySessionAuthenticationStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy {
    int MAX_USERS = 1000; // Whatever
    SessionRegistry sr;

    public MySessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistry sr) {
        super(sr);
        this.sr = sr;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthentication(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (sr.getAllPrincipals().size() > MAX_USERS) {
            throw new SessionAuthenticationException("Maximum number of users exceeded");
        }
        super.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
    }
}
```

You would then inject this into the security namespace as described in [the Spring Security reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#concurrent-sessions).

In Spring Security 2.0, the concurrent session control is implemented slightly differently and you would customize the ConcurrentSessionController instead.

Comment: One point about getAllPrincipals is that it returns principals from expired sessions as well. I found myself having to loop through all sessions with sr.getAllSessions() to check that I wasn't counting expired ones. My max_users was much smaller and the expired sessions weren't being cleared out fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment. But getAllPrincipals returns all principals including ones from expired sessions. Use some method like below to getAllActiveSessions.

```
private List<SessionInformation> getActiveSessions(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
    final List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    if (principals != null) {
        List<SessionInformation> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object principal : principals) {
            sessions.addAll(sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal,     false));
        }
        return sessions;
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this post is a bit old but I have had the same problem in spring security 4.1 and I have solved it like that.

session-management

```
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <security:session-management  invalid-session-url="/app/login" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy">                                   
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>
```

session-authentication-strategy-ref

```
<bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
            <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
            <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
            <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        </bean>
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

SessionRegistry

```java
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```

Authentication

```java
List<SessionInformation> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
    sessions.addAll(sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false));
}
LOGGER.info("Sessiones Activas: " + sessions.size());
// filtro para limite de sessiones
if (sessions.size() < max_sessions) {
//authentication
} else {
    throw new SessionAuthenticationException("Maximo numero de Usuarios exedido.");
}
```

in this way because I am authenticating based on security: custom-filter