# Spring Max Sessions on Application, NOT Max Sessions for a User on an Application

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

Im writting a web app using jhipster. And it is using spring. I was trying to limit the number of times the same user can log in into my application and got that to work on a file named `ServerConfiguration.java` with this:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
        .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .permitAll()
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .and()            
        .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("spring.maxuser.sessions")))
                 .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }


@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

This makes a particular user only log in so many times into my application.

Now, The question that i have is how do I make my application only be open/accessible for `x` number of `different` users. For example, I want my application to only be accessed by 200 users. And when user 201 comes along and wants to log in, then it cannot.

I saw on this other post [spring limit max sessions ; limit max users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106601/spring-limit-max-sessions-limit-max-users/36716273?noredirect=1#comment61022054_36716273]) an answer but I do not know where to put this code exactly.

```
public class MySessionAuthenticationStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy {
int MAX_USERS = 1000; // Whatever
SessionRegistry sr;

public MySessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistry sr) {
    super(sr);
    this.sr = sr;
}

@Override
public void onAuthentication(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (sr.getAllPrincipals().size() > MAX_USERS) {
        throw new SessionAuthenticationException("Maximum number of users exceeded");
    }
    super.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
}
```

}

Were should I create this new class `MySessionAuthenticationStrategy` And how do I go from my httpConfigure class to this new class `MySessionAuthenticationStrategy`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Create a class to extend the default session registry:

```
@Component
public class MySessionRegistry extends org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl {    
}
```

Update your configure method to look like this.

```
    @Autowired
    MySessionRegistry sessionRegistry; 
    void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
                .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("spring.maxuser.sessions")))
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }
```

Then during login/authentication, try this:

```
    @Autowired
    MySessionRegistry sessionRegistry; 

    public void onAuthentication(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (calculateMaxSessions(sessionRegistry) > MAX_USERS) {
            throw new SessionAuthenticationException("Maximum number of users exceeded");
        } else {
            //Authenticate
        }
    }

    public int calculateMaxSessions(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry){
        final List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
        if (principals != null) {
            List<SessionInformation> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object principal : principals) {
                sessions.addAll(sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false));
            }
            return sessions.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. 
1- So I just need to create this empty class
2- Then add a new instance of my newly created class on my `SecurityConfiguration.java` calss. I do not know how Autowired works exactly. Then add this new attribute: `sessionsRegistry(myNewlyCreatedClassInstance)`
3- I do not know where exactly I do my login/authentication.... :( THis is the first time I look at this spring stuff. Where do I put this?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can add this at your WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .invalidSessionUrl("/")
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .expiredUrl("/login?invalid-session=true");
    }
```

and override equals() and hash() in your CustomUserDetails class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof CustomUserDetails)) return false;
    CustomUserDetails that = (CustomUserDetails) o;
    return user.getUsername().equals(that.user.getUsername()) &&
            user.getEmailAddress().equals(that.user.getEmailAddress()) &&
            user.getPassword().equals(that.user.getPassword());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    
    return Objects.hash(user.getUsername(), user.getEmailAddress(), user.getPassword());
}
```