# Limit the total amount of sessions in a Sprint Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, load, session-management

In our Spring Boot web server, I know how to limit the sessions per user (`httpSecurity.sessionManagement().maximumSessions()`), but I want to limit the total amount of sessions, to avoid load on the server.

How can this be done?

Comment: Load doesn't come from sessions. It comes from requests. All containers already have a thread pool limiting the number of concurrent requests. 2 people sending a request every 2 seconds cause a higher load than 30 people sending a request every minute (assuming all requests are equivalent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring limit max sessions ; limit max users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106601/spring-limit-max-sessions-limit-max-users) and of [Spring Max Sessions on Application, NOT Max Sessions for a User on an Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722947)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'total number of users' is a meaningful proxy for 'load' (see the comment from @JBNizet) in your system e.g. if most requests are ~identical in terms of resource footprint then you could define your own implementation of `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`. Here's a simple example:

```
private class AllUsersConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy {

    // probably inject this from application configuration
    private final int maxUsers;
    private final SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    public AllUsersConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(int maxUsers, SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        super(sessionRegistry);
        this.maxUsers = maxUsers;
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthentication(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size() > maxUsers) {
            throw new SessionAuthenticationException("...");
        }
        super.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
    }
}
```

You register this like so:

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new AllUsersConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(maxUsers, sessionRegistry));
```

However, if 'total number of users' is **not** a meaningful proxy for 'load' then you should perhaps consider implementing your services in a non-blocking manner with each endpoint passing its request off to a threadpool and the request-to-threadpool allocation strategy could take into account how 'heavy' the request is. Lightweight requests could be handled by a *large* threadpool, heavyweitgh requests could be handled by a *smaller* threadpool.