# Spring Security limitation of concurrent login users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my REST api, i want to implement limitation of concurrent login users (oauth token). There might be 100 registered users in the database, say, the maximum of concurrent login users is 2 (this value stored in database), when `adam@gmail.com` and `ken@gmail.com` logged in, it will block the subsequent login attempts.

In the internet i can only find example of maximum session PER user.

Any hints that i can leverage from out of the box solution from spring security?

Comment: Check that one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106601/spring-limit-max-sessions-limit-max-users

Comment: You cannot, you will have to write something which integrates with spring security yourself. Also are you really sure you want this? As this could potentially lock out other users for the duration of the whole session time, when a user doesn't logout he lingers around until the session times out. Now if you have 2 users it could very well be that your application is inaccessible for half an hour (the default session timeout).